# PHP - How to divide a day in 3 shifts

Tags: php

I have a database where i keep the time of production of items. For some reasom i can't divide in 3 shifts.

On my code (php) i first get the hour ($rest) of production (from 00 to 23) and them i try to use the if function to say if is A, B or C Shift base on the $rest.

Here's my code:

```
$rest = substr("$time", -8, 2);
if ($rest > 06 or $rest < 15) {
    $shift = "A"}
if ($rest > 14 or $rest < 23) {
    $shift = "B"}
if ($rest > 22 or $rest < 07) {
    $shift = "C"}
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to use `AND` instead of `OR` for the first two `IF` statements.  You should probably want to use `IF/ELSE IF/ELSE` instead of 3 IFs.

Comment: What is a sample value of `$time`?

Comment: also you are using Octal Numbers - you know that right ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: $time = "h:m:s" like.. 11:46:34 for example!

Comment: @birdspider while this is true (and is probably not intentional), in the given example it makes no difference.

Comment: @Matthew yeah I know - but I couldn't just ignore it either

Comment: Of course, I was just being pedantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finaly got the right result. the way to do it is using the next code:

```
$rest = substr($time, -8, 2);
if ($rest >= 00){
 $shift ="C";}{
if ($rest > 06){
 $shift ="A";}{
if ($rest >14){
 $shift ="B"}
if ($rest>22){
$shift ="C";}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You switch `and` for `or`

```
$rest = substr($time, -8, 2);
if ($rest > 06 && $rest < 15) {
    $shift ="A";
} else if ($rest > 14 && $rest < 23) {
    $shift ="B";
} else {
    $shift ="C";
}
```

Comment: That dident help, since it diden't change the result. And i need to separate in intervals.. A = 07 to 15, B =15 to 23 and C=23 to 07

Comment: @Mestre1966: I know, what you need, and thiscode do that. What you have in your own answer below, it´s st. similar to my question, only in worse and slower package.